# Select table view in editing mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to push two different view controllers: 1). When tableView is in "normal mode" 2). When the table view is in editing mode. The edit button is on my navigation bar. When the Table View is in "normal mode" I can select a cell, It turns blue and pushes my View Controller. How can I make it so that the table view is able to be selected while in edit mode? Here is what i have done so far:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initForNewItem:NO];

[detailViewController setItem:selectedItem];

 //This doesnt work because i cant select the cell  
 if(aTableView.editing){

   [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

} else {
//push something else     
}
```

Comment: If your tableview is in another view controller, you need to put the method for editing into that view controller.

Comment: @DustinRowland ya I have it declared in a different void.

Comment: So the problem is that you can't push another view controller with your navigation controller when the table is in editing mode, correct?

Comment: It's not conventional tableview behavior to let another controller be pushed while in editing mode, but it might work if you use `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:`. Just copy  your code into it.

Comment: @DustinRowland Sorry didnt work. Maybe I will just need to find a another way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should set the UITableView property allowsSelectionDuringEditing to YES (by default it's NO). Try to set it in the LoadView, not in the init.